# Creating a loading alert on jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a newbie on javascript. I am trying create an App wherein I am able to alert the user to wait while loading.My intention is to have the loading bar disappear right before the user gets an alert on whether data was submitted successfully or not. The problem however is that the loading bar remains visible until one presses ok on the alert window.

```
$("#bkssubmit").click(function(){
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
var data=$("#myForm :input").serializeArray();
$.post($("#myForm").attr("action"),data,function(info){
$("#result").html(info);
});
```

Comment: just dont add the ajax handlers inside the click handler

Answer (score 1):

What your code does: "when someone clicks the submit button, add those event handlers to the document". Whereas you can add the ajax handlers before hand:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});

$("#bkssubmit").click(function(){
  // your ajax stuff
});
```

Comment: It still exhibits the same behaviour. To shed more light, this file posts to a php file which queries a database and brings a response like:

Comment: if(// num rows is less than 1){}

Comment: sorry I'm messing up stack. Was saying the php already has a javascript response  echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Book is not returned")';
        echo '</script>';

Comment: Your php response is incorrect - it should not respond with javascript, it should respond with *data* - ie return an object (eg JSON) with success=false, message="Book not returned" and let the js handle it.